# Instagram Graph API - business_discovery(username) returns invalid user but account exists

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm in a war with Instagram Graph API (as everybody nowdays) and trying to understand the documentation which doesn't explain a lot of things.

In this battle, I've been able to get information from Instagram accounts thru business_discovery(username) more or less, but there are some accounts that return error:

```
"error": {
    "message": "Invalid user id",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 110,
    "error_subcode": 2207013,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "No se encuentra el usuario",
    "error_user_msg": "No se encuentra el usuario davidbroncano.",
    "fbtrace_id": "AaBNG1ii7N7I2Hksa4PctZ_"
}
```

Same response with other accounts that I know they exists and they are public.

So, my questions are:

1. Why?
2. How can I know that an account is reachable thru the Graph API?

Comment: 1. Are those Business/Creator accounts? 2. Deduce it from the fact that you are _not_ getting this error?

Comment: @CBroe 1. Well, how can I know that? I've got this issue with a famous person account, with a football team account, with normal people accounts... Not getting a lot of answers to know the API's criteria. 2. Well, I was hoping a more elegant solution, I've already reached that logic. Maybe I should be more specific and ask "How can I know if an account is business/creator and I can get the data or it would return an error?"

Comment: The Basic Display API has an `account_type` field on the User object. So as long as you have an access token including `instagram_graph_user_profile` for the account in question, you could use that to check first.

Comment: But, I can't use the Basic Display API to query business/creators accounts, right?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/user#fields says `account_type` _“can be BUSINESS, MEDIA_CREATOR, or PERSONAL”_, so I don’t think it would make sense if you couldn’t.

Comment: To use that endpoint I need user's ID, which I don't have because I'm not able to know that the user actually exists thru "business.discovery".

Comment: Did anyone figure this out, what was happening here? @AndrésMarotta

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if the user has changed their username on Instagram. In case you've stored the username on your database, you'd have to fetch it again and update it every time you need to make a call so that you avoid this error.